# What is the right exponent $x=x(p, q)$ such that both $a^p\le (a+b)^x$ and $b^q\le (a+b)^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, elementary-functions

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ and $p, q\in\mathbb{R}, p, q>1$. I would like to find the right exponent $x$ (clearly $x$ depending on $p$ and $q$), such that
$$ a^p\le (a+b)^x \quad\mbox{ and }\quad b^q\le (a+b)^x.$$

Could someone please suggest some possible options? Every hints or idea is well accepted.

Thank you in advance!

$\bf EDIT:$ for the case $a+b>1$, I think that the answer of Gareth Ma works. What about the case $0<a+b<1$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Taking logarithms, the equations give $p\log a\leq x\log(a + b)$ and $q\log b\leq x\log(a + b)$. Therefore, we need (assuming $a + b > 1$)

$$\begin{cases} x&\geq \frac{1}{\log(a + b)} \max\{p\log a, q\log b\} 
&\text{if}\ a + b > 1 \\ x &\leq \frac{1}{\log(a + b)} \min\{p\log a, q\log b\}&\text{if}\ a + b < 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Gareth Ma, and what about if $0<a+b<1$?

Comment: @C.Bishop We have $\log(a + b) < 0$, so when you divide both sides to isolate $x$ the sign will be flipped.

Comment: Thanks. There is a formula which can cover both cases?

Comment: @C.Bishop It won't be nice.

Comment: No matter :) Would you please edit the answer with that part? Thank you in advance.